# How do I need to configure my Java project to make a connection with IronMQ?

Tags: java, queue, server, ironmq

I downloaded the libraries and the json file with the connection settings. I put the file in the same level that Mensajes's class, where I try to make the connection.
In the class I didn't know how to call the settings on the json file so I found that I can do it replacing the project_id and token in the code below. I did it but still send me an error.

```
public Mensajes() throws IOException {               
Client client = new Client("project_id","token",Cloud.ironAWSUSEast);          
Queue queue = client.queue("Example_Queue");               
String push = queue.push("Hello world!");
System.out.println(push);         
}
```

The error that's given me is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.iron.ironmq.HTTPException: Not found
    at io.iron.ironmq.Client.singleRequest(Client.java:231)
    at io.iron.ironmq.Client.request(Client.java:164)
    at io.iron.ironmq.Client.post(Client.java:145)
    at io.iron.ironmq.Queue.push(Queue.java:367)
    at io.iron.ironmq.Queue.push(Queue.java:329)
    at io.iron.ironmq.Queue.push(Queue.java:302)
    at cajerobanco.Mensajes.<init>(Mensajes.java:26)
    at cajerobanco.CajeroBanco.main(CajeroBanco.java:20)
```

I don't know how to do it and I already tried to look for answers on the web but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi @Mel, did you se the project_id and token correctly?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Travis, the next day I realize that project_id and token were upside but even changing them the error still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there was a problem with the library, when I downloaded the files and create the library myself I could do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about the fix you found for your own problem?

Comment: I downloaded the .jar of the library and that .jar had a problem, so I downloaded the files and just put them on a folder and everything worked fine.